# Making a program that count

Tags: c#

When I input a word like for example `hello` it prints this  `4 + 1 + 3 + 3 + 1 += 12`

```
            Console.Write("Give a word: ");
            string word = Console.ReadLine();
            string smallword = word.ToLower();


            int sum = 0;
            foreach (char letter in smallword)
            {
                int index = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, letter);
                int score = scores[index];
                sum = sum + score;
                string addingEverythingTogether = $" {score} +";
                Console.Write(addingEverythingTogether);
            }
            Console.Write($"= {sum}");
```

But it should be printing this  `4 + 1 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 12`. The same line but with out the extra "+" at the end. How can I remove this last '+'?

Comment: BTW: you get in trouble if your input contains any character not in `alphabet`.

Answer (score -1):

When you have your smallword filled something like

```
var numbers = smallword.Select(c => scores[Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c)]);
Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(" + ", numbers)}= {numbers.Sum()}");
```

Answer (score -1):

LINQ is your friend:

```cs
var word = Console.ReadLine();
var wordScores = word.Select(ch => scores[Array.IndexOf(alphabet, char.ToLower(ch))])
                     .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(" + ", wordScores.Cast<object>())} = {wordScores.Sum()}");
```

LINQ is a great way to flatten loops into more succinct statements. The `Select` method will get you all the scores that correspond to the letters in the word. the `string.Join` method then does what you specifically asked about, i.e. creates a single `string` from multiple values with the specified delimiter between them. The single call to `Sum` will add up all the scores in that array.

The `Cast` call may be unnecessary but I think that `string.Join` doesn't work with value-type lists, so that call boxes each `int` value and produces an `IEnumerable<object>`, which should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can refactor your code like this and you can use LINQ to help you;

```cs
private static readonly Dictionary<char, int> _scores = new Dictionary<char, int>
{
    { 'a', 1 }, { 'b', 3 }, { 'c', 5 }, { 'd', 2 }, { 'e', 1 }, { 'f', 4 }, { 'g', 3 },
    { 'h', 4 }, { 'i', 1 }, { 'j', 4 }, { 'k', 3 }, { 'l', 3 }, { 'm', 3 }, { 'n', 1 },
    { 'o', 1 }, { 'p', 3 }, { 'q', 10 }, { 'r', 2 }, { 's', 2 }, { 't', 2 }, { 'u', 4 },
    { 'v', 4 }, { 'w', 5 }, { 'x', 8 }, { 'y', 8 }, { 'z', 4 }
};

public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Geef een word: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine().ToLowerInvariant();

    var scores = input.Select(c => _scores[c]).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(" + ", scores)} = {scores.Sum()}"); // 4 + 1 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 12
}
```

You simply create a dictionary to hold your letters and corresponding scores. Then you just access to the score with just passing the letter. No nede for creating 2 arrays, getting index from the first array and then access to second list's index etc.